# why product of range(1,35) is equal to zero?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to learn python, numpy package. I was evaluating the following code

```
import numpy as np
>>> np.prod(range(1,33))
-2147483648
>>> np.prod(range(1,34))
-2147483648
>>> np.prod(range(1,35))
0
```

Why `np.prod(range(1,35))` equals zero ?
and why `np.prod(range(1,34))` is a negative value ?

Comment: What version of numpy and python are you using? `-2147483648` looks like a signed  32 bit long, are you running this on windows?

Comment: `Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32` numpy verion `1.8.2`

Comment: Ok that is the problem , you have an overflow error, the max value of a signed  32 bit long is `2,147,483,647`, `np.prod(range(1,34)) ->  3400198294675128320`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29 
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python's builtin integers are built to store infinitely large numbers. However, as the number grows, the cost of doing mathematical operations on them grows.

On the other hand, Numpy uses a set of fixed size integers. These numbers have maximum sizes (Often `2**31`, and `2**63`) that relate to the hardware that is available on your computer. This allows numpy to implement very fast mathematical operations, but at the cost of having a maximum values that can be stored.

You are overflowing the maximum value that numpy allows.

```
>>> int(np.prod(range(1,21))) * 22
53523844179886080000L

>>> np.prod(range(1,21)) * 22
-1816388041242574848

>>> int(np.prod(range(1,21))) * 22 > 2**64
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Arithmetic is modular when using integer types, and no error is raised on overflow.  Check the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html)

```
>>> x = np.array([536870910, 536870910, 536870910, 536870910])
>>> np.prod(x) #random
16
```